# Type com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzdb is referenced as an interface from `com.google.android.gms.analytics.AnalyticsJobService`

Tags: android, firebase, build.gradle, android-r8

I have already gone through similar posts on github and SO but not sure which combination is causing conflict.

This combination of dependencies works in debug build but release build getting an error -

```
Type com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzdb is referenced as an interface from `com.google.android.gms.analytics.AnalyticsJobService`.
```

Gradle Dependencies and versions :

```
// Play services dependencies
api deps.playcore
api deps.play_services.analytics
api deps.play_services.auth
api deps.play_services.base
api deps.play_services.core
api deps.play_services.location
api deps.play_services.plus
api deps.play_services.tagmanager

// Firebase dependencies
api deps.firebase.analytics
api deps.firebase.config
api deps.firebase.app_indexing
api deps.firebase.messaging
api deps.firebase.performance

//versions
versions.play_services_analytics = '16.0.4'
versions.play_services_auth = '17.0.0'
versions.play_services_base = '17.1.0'
versions.play_services_core = '17.1.2'
versions.play_services_location = '17.0.0'
versions.play_services_plus = '17.0.0'
versions.play_services_tagmanager = '17.0.0'
versions.play_core = '1.5.0'

versions.firebase_analytics = '17.2.0'
versions.firebase_app_indexing = '19.0.0'
versions.firebase_config = '17.2.0'
versions.firebase_dynamic_links = '19.0.0'
versions.firebase_messaging = '20.0.0'
versions.firebase_perf = '19.0.0'
```